# getting connection refused while connecting to redis-cli

Tags: redis

I am getting this error while connecting redis-cli. Please help me to fix this.

```
tony@kali:~$ redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected>
```

Comment: Please provide some configuration and environment details. Also your client network details. Without details, nobody can help you out.

Answer (score 10):

i learned my mistake what was i did was first i started redis-server when that show i'm connected to port i pressed ctrl + c in keyboard then i tried to start redis cli but later i got it after several attempt that i have to use this command to start redis

```
            redis-server & redis-cli
```

Comment: on mac "src/redis-cli & src/redis-server" works for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you installed redis with brew, you have to do the following first:

brew services start redis

Answer (score 1):

I got the following error on first attempt to start the redis-server:
           ********************
22:M 17 May 2020 11:00:58.705 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
                                                                                          22:M 17 May 2020 11:00:58.706 # Server initialized
                    22:M 17 May 2020 11:00:58.707 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! 
Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
                                                                22:M 17 May 2020 11:00:58.710 * 
Ready to accept connections
not connected>
          *********

i modified the 'sysctl.conf' file and added the line .. reloaded the Ubuntu App. It resolved the issue.

---

68:M 17 May 2020 11:09:35.023 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
68:M 17 May 2020 11:09:35.027 # Server initialized
68:M 17 May 2020 11:09:35.028 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
68:M 17 May 2020 11:09:35.032 * Ready to accept connections

root@US-00008275:~# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set user1:SP
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
127.0.0.1:6379> set user1:1 "SP"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get user1:1
"SP"
127.0.0.1:6379>

---

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command and then try redis-cli

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```